# How can I exclude urls from Sitemap Generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, sitemap

Since I didn't find a good (and free) tool on the web to generate my sitemap I decide to create a JavaScript script from scratch, everything works but since I'm not very good with regex I need some help.

I have this function used to process my Sitemap:

```
function processSitemap(myUrl,maxLinks,countMe,checkDate,customDate,defPriority,defFreq){
        jQuery.post('../?route=ajax',{sitemap:'1', url:myUrl},function(data){
        var resData = data.split("::|::"); 
        var resCount = parseInt(resData[0]);
        var resLinkData = resData[1];
        var resLinks = resLinkData.split("\n"); 
        var ccLinks = [];
        jQuery(".linksCount").html('<br/>Crawling Link: '+ myUrl +'<br/>Links Found: ' + resLinks.length);

        for (var i = 0; i < resLinks.length; i++) {
        var ccData = resLinks[i].trim();
        if(jQuery.inArray(ccData, linksArr) == -1){
        ccLinks.push(ccData);  
        countLinks++;
        if(countLinks != maxLinks){
        jQuery("#resultList").append('&lt;url&gt;'+'\n'); 
        jQuery("#resultList").append('  &lt;loc&gt;'+ ccData + '&lt;/loc&gt;' + '\n'); 
        if(defPriority != 'N/A'){
        jQuery("#resultList").append('  &lt;priority&gt;'+ defPriority + '&lt;/priority&gt;' + '\n'); 
        }
        if(defFreq != 'N/A'){
        defFreqT = defFreq.toString().toLowerCase();
        jQuery("#resultList").append('  &lt;changefreq&gt;'+ defFreqT + '&lt;/changefreq&gt;' + '\n'); 
        }
        if(checkDate != 'N/A'){
            if(checkDate == '1'){
            var fullDate = new Date();
            var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth()+1+"";if(twoDigitMonth.length==1)  twoDigitMonth="0" +twoDigitMonth;
            var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate()+"";if(twoDigitDate.length==1) twoDigitDate="0" +twoDigitDate;
            var currentDate = fullDate.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + twoDigitDate;
            jQuery("#resultList").append('  &lt;lastmod&gt;'+ currentDate + '&lt;/lastmod&gt;' + '\n'); 
            }
            if(checkDate == '2'){
            customDate = customDate.trim();customDate=customDate.split('/');
            customDate = customDate[2] + "-" + customDate[1] + "-" + customDate[0];
            jQuery("#resultList").append('  &lt;lastmod&gt;'+ customDate + '&lt;/lastmod&gt;' + '\n');   
            }
        }
        jQuery("#resultList").append('&lt;/url&gt;'+'\n');
        }else{
          jQuery(".percentimg").fadeOut();
          jQuery("#resultList").append('&lt;/urlset&gt;');
          jQuery(".genCount").html('<br/>Sitemap generated for ' + countLinks + ' links!');
          break;
        }
        }
        }
        if(countLinks == maxLinks){
            return false;
        }
        if (countMe == maxLinksCrawl){
          jQuery(".percentimg").fadeOut();
          jQuery("#resultList").append('&lt;/urlset&gt;');
          jQuery(".genCount").html('<br/>Crawler Limit Reached! <br/> Sitemap generated for ' + countLinks + ' links!');
          return false;
        }
        else{
        linksArr = linksArr.concat(ccLinks);
        myUrl= linksArr[countMe];
        countMe++;
        if (parseInt(countMe) < parseInt(linksArr.length)) {
        processSitemap(myUrl,maxLinks,countMe,checkDate,customDate,defPriority,defFreq);
        }
        else{
          jQuery(".percentimg").fadeOut();
          jQuery("#resultList").append('&lt;/urlset&gt;');
          jQuery(".genCount").html('<br/>Sitemap generated for ' + countLinks + ' links!');
          return false;
        }
        }
    });
}
```

Using regex I wish to exclude from `data` some unwanted urls like

```
https://example.com/notifications&filter=chats
https://example.com/page&b=repost
```

What's the easiest way?

Comment: you want to remove every URL that begins from `https://example.com`?

Comment: @rock321987 I wish to exclude all `/notifications*` and all `&b=repost`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following test into your callback function:

```
function(data){
    // ...
    for (var i = 0; i < resLinks.length; i++) {
        if (resLinks[i].match(/(\/notifications&|&b=repost)/)) {
            continue;
        }
        //...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to find all the url with `example.com` followed by `notifications` or `&b=repost`

```
https:\/\/example.com\/(?=.*(notifications|&b=repost))
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mM7hL8/1)**